# How to implement a .Debounce() / .DebounceDistinct() extension methods for observable streams in RXNet (C#)?

Tags: c#, .net, reactive-programming, system.reactive, rx.net

Essentially what the subject says. I can't find any ready-made .Debounce() extension-method (similar to how Throttle() is available out-of-the-box).

Following below is a rough and probably faulty idea of how it could be implemented (based on my understanding of rxnet mentality).

I'm already aware that the following implementation is most probably not thread-safe and it also comfounds debounce with distinct which is not ideal. Some better ideas are needed to make this robust:

```
        /// <summary>
        /// Emits an element from the source observable sequence if and only if there are no other elements emitted during a given period of time specified by debounceTime.
        /// </summary>
        /// <typeparam name="TSource">The type of the elements in the source sequence.</typeparam>
        /// <param name="source">Source sequence to debounce.</param>
        /// <param name="debounceTime">Debouncing duration for each element.</param>
        /// <param name="customComparer">The customComparer to use to compare each next element with the previous one</param>
        /// <returns>The debounced sequence.</returns>
        /// <exception cref="ArgumentNullException"><paramref name="source"/> is null.</exception>
        /// <exception cref="ArgumentOutOfRangeException"><paramref name="debounceTime"/> is less than TimeSpan.Zero.</exception>
        /// <remarks>
        /// <para>
        /// This operator debounces the source sequence by holding on to each element for the duration specified in <paramref name="debounceTime"/>. If another
        /// element is produced within this time window, the previous element is dropped and a new timer is started for the current element to try and debounce it,
        /// thus restarting this whole process. For streams that never have gaps larger than or equal to <paramref name="debounceTime"/> between elements, the resulting
        /// stream won't produce any elements at all. In order to reduce the volume of a stream whilst guaranteeing the periodic production of elements, consider using the
        /// Observable.Sample set of operators.
        /// </para>
        /// </remarks>
        static public IObservable<TSource> DebounceX<TSource>(this IObservable<TSource> source, TimeSpan debounceTime, IEqualityComparer<TSource> customComparer = null)
        {
            if (source == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(source));
            if (debounceTime.TotalMilliseconds <= 0) throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(debounceTime));

            var debouncedElementsStream = Observable.Create<TSource>(Subscribe);

            return debouncedElementsStream;
            
            IDisposable Subscribe(IObserver<TSource> observer)
            {
                //substream of stable elements
                var timer = (Timer)null;
                var previousElement = default(TSource);

                var comparer = customComparer ?? EqualityComparer<TSource>.Default;

                return source.Subscribe(onNext: OnEachElementEmission_, onError: OnError_, onCompleted: OnCompleted_);

                void OnEachElementEmission_(TSource value)
                {
                    if (timer != null && comparer.Equals(previousElement, value)) return;

                    previousElement = value;

                    timer?.Dispose();
                    timer = new Timer(
                        state: null,
                        period: Timeout.InfiniteTimeSpan, //  we only want the timer to fire once
                        dueTime: debounceTime, //             after the debounce time has passed
                        callback: _ => OnElementHasRemainedStableForTheSpecificPeriod(value)
                    );
                }

                void OnError_(Exception exception)
                {
                    timer?.Dispose();
                    timer = null;

                    observer.OnError(exception);
                }

                void OnCompleted_()
                {
                    timer?.Dispose();
                    timer = null;

                    observer.OnCompleted();
                }

                void OnElementHasRemainedStableForTheSpecificPeriod(TSource value)
                {
                    timer?.Dispose();
                    timer = null;

                    observer.OnNext(value); //00

                    //00  OnNext(value) essentially emits in the stream the debounced element that has remained stable for the whole period of time specified by debounceTime
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Seems like a candidate for code review SE to me ... but off topic on SO in its current form.

Comment: Posted the answer as I understand it. If it does not suit your needs - please post expected output examples for various scenarios (with/without duplicates)

Comment: @XDS - don't post code relevant to the question as an answer. Make the answer standalone.

Comment: @Enigmativity Upon creating a new question stackoverflow immediately offers in the UI the option to create an answer to the question that's about to be created. That in itself is a profound tell-sign from SO's behalf on how it's intended to be used - do I miss something?

Comment: @XDS - Once you have a fully formed question you can answer it, but your question says you've put the implementation of `Debounce` in an answer, but it's really part of the question. Otherwise you're asking us to code for you. If you post your code in the question then you're asking us to help you with your code. The first is off-topic here, but the second way is good.

Comment: Now, with that edit, your question is off-topic.

Comment: @Enigmativity Fair enough. Thanks for pointing out the change in mentality in SO. In previous years I would post questions without posting any sample-code in it and it would get green-lit. I will keep your advise in mind going forward.

Comment: @XDS - It's not a change in mentality. Nothing gets "green-lit" here. It just fails to get "red-lit". If you've done it in the past you've just been lucky.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this example pls, it is debouncing without checking for duplicates:

```
static async Task Main()
{
    IObservable<T> Debounce<T>(IObservable<T> source, TimeSpan delay)
    {
        return source
        .Do(x => TimestampedPrint($"Source: {x}"))
        .Select(x => Observable.Return(x).Delay(delay))
        .Switch();
    }
    void TimestampedPrint(object o) => Console.WriteLine($"{DateTime.Now:HH.mm.ss.fff}: {o}");

    Subject<int> subject = new Subject<int>();

    Debounce(subject, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1))
    .Subscribe(x => TimestampedPrint($"Result: {x}"));

    subject.OnNext(1);
    Thread.Sleep(1100);
    subject.OnNext(2);
    Thread.Sleep(1100);
    subject.OnNext(3);
    Thread.Sleep(500);
    subject.OnNext(4);
    Thread.Sleep(500);
    subject.OnNext(5);

    Console.ReadLine();

}
```

Resulting:

```
23.24.58.633: Started
23.24.58.676: Source: 1
23.24.59.708: Result: 1
23.24.59.783: Source: 2
23.25.00.785: Result: 2
23.25.00.884: Source: 3
23.25.01.386: Source: 4
23.25.01.888: Source: 5
23.25.02.888: Result: 5
```

The extension WITH equality comparer, if I got your idea right:

```
    IObservable<T> Debounce<T>(IObservable<T> source, TimeSpan delay, IEqualityComparer<T> comparer = null)
    {
        return source
        .Do(x => TimestampedPrint($"Source: {x}"))
        .DistinctUntilChanged(comparer ?? EqualityComparer<T>.Default)
        .Select(x => Observable.Return(x).Delay(delay))
        .Switch();
    }
```

This case gives me the following output, when publishing only "1"s:

```
23.26.30.288: Started
23.26.30.346: Source: 1
23.26.31.376: Result: 1
23.26.31.455: Source: 1
23.26.32.557: Source: 1
23.26.33.057: Source: 1
23.26.33.558: Source: 1
```

Comment: This is amazing. I was thinking of something similar with .Delay() but I couldn't see how the pieces of the puzzle fit until I saw the way you employ .Switch()! I haven't tested it yet but my first impression is that it makes absolute sense - this is so sublime it's astounding! Quick questions: (a) Is this thread safe too? Will things work as intended in corner-cases where multiple threads are placing items on the source-subject? (b) How come such elegance is not standardized in a standard .Debounce() method baked right into RxNet?

Comment: @XDS a) You can make any input thread safe simply adding .Synchronize() operator. b) Have no idea, probably because it is fairly simple to implement?

Comment: you rock - much appreciated!